# post data with jQuery and redirect to another action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

View:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Index</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {

   $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#example").submit(function() {
        var id = $("#id").val();
        var prezime = $("#prezime").val();

        $.post("/jQueryPost/PostingData", { id: id, prezime: prezime }, function(res) {
            if (res.redirect) {
                window.location.href = res.redirect;
                return;
            }

        }, "json");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<form id="example" method = "post">

    Id:<input id="id" type="text" />
    Prezime:<input id="prezime" type="text" />

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Post Data" />
</p>
</form>

</asp:Content>
```

Controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostingData(int id, string prezime)
    {

        //some code

        return Json(new { redirect = Url.Action("Create") });
    }
```

Tnx, this code solve my problem

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903685/jquery-preventing-redirecttoaction-from-working).

Comment: Any reason you need to use javascript to post your form?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of returning a redirect, which the AJAX request can't handle, return the URL as JSON and let the post handler change the location.

```
$.post("/jQueryPost/PostingData", { id: id, prezime: prezime }, function(data) {
    location = data.url;
});

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostingData(int id, string prezime)
{

    //some code

    return Json( new { url = Url.Action( "Create" ) } );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the redirect doesn't work is because you are doing an asynchronous request. The response that contains the code for the redirection is just returned as data to the success method, where you ignore it.

Instead, just post the form that you have in the page:

```
$('#example').attr('action', '/jQueryPost/PostingData/').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

controller

```
public ActionResult DeleteMenuItem(int id)
{
    _menuService.DeleteMenuItemById(id);
    return Json(new { url = Url.Action("Index","Menu") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View

```
$.getJSON( "/Menu/DeleteMenuItem", { id: parseInt(id)}, function(data) {
    location = data.url;
} );
```